# Method BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits (Double) in C#

Tags: c#

This method convert a double value  into its bit representation formatted in hexadecimal format. Why is specified that the converted value is a signed int64 ?   Which is the difference with unsigned int64 ? The binary representation of the double is unique.

Comment: Unsigned types are strongly avoided in the framework, they are not [CLSCompliant].  That mattered a lot back in the olden days, JScript and VB.NET were core .NET languages but did not (yet) have unsigned type support.  In many practical cases it just doesn't matter, it doesn't here.

Answer (score 3):

First off, that method does not convert it to hexadecimal, it converts the bits to be interpreted as an `Int64`, which you could then convert to a hexadecimal string if you chose, using `ToString("X")` or some such.

There is no difference between a signed `Int64` and unsigned `UInt64` under the hood-- the only difference is how the 64-bit word is interpreted by your program.

A 64-bit double is also a 64-bit word, under the hood-- but some processors, like intel x86 family of processors, support an 80-bit double precision floating point, not just a 64-bit double.  That method is simply allowing C# to interpret the bits for a 64-bit double (or convert an 80-bit double to a 64-bit double, if that's what it has to work with) as if it were a 64-bit signed int.  If you want to interpret that as a 64-bit unsigned int, just cast it (using unchecked to prevent c# from freaking out):

```
ulong bitsForDouble;
unchecked {
    bitsForDouble = (ulong)BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(someDoubleValue);
}
```

It doesn't make sense to interpret the bits of a double as either an `Int64` or a `UInt64`-- they just wanted to give us a way to represent a double in a 64-bit value for whatever bit manipulation needs we might have.